# Setting select value has no effect on keyboard use

Tags: jquery

I have a select with f.e. 10 options ('one', 'two', 'three', ...). Loading the page the first option 'one' is selected.

Within a function I set to fifth option

```
$("myselect").val('five');
```

In fact now fifths option is shown in select and value also is set correct.

But now I tab on in my form until I reach this select. And if I now use keyboard down key, the select jumps to option 'two' and not 'six'.

How to set a selected option which works for a later keyboard use, too?

Comment: Seems to happen only in Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/JM2dZ/

Comment: Works in Chrome, but not Firefox.  Even clicking on the dropdown doesn't help.

Comment: Here's a jQuery bug with the same issue: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11488

Comment: You might consider up-voting people that help you, if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the `selectedIndex` property. See below,

```
$('#myselect').val("5").prop('selectedIndex', 4);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kLZ7z/

Another better cleaner approach is

```
var nValue = "5";
$('option', '#myselect').filter(function () {        
    return this.value == nValue;
}).prop('selected', true);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kLZ7z/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is a Firefox bug.  One solution I found is to use `.prop('selected', true)` on the option, instead of using `.val` on the select.

```
$('#myselect').children('option[value="five"]').prop('selected', true);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JM2dZ/1/

NOTE: You don't need to unset `selected` on the other options first, doing so will actually cause the issue to keep happening.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing a bit, but try this:

```
$('#myselect option').each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('selected'));
});
$('#myselect option').eq(4).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

That's a bit of untested pseudo-code, just to give you an idea of what to try.

Comment: does not work (also the answer form Asad does not). - but what i just found out - it seems to be a firefox issue, as IE and chrome do like expected

Comment: @FabianKnauf: Try with out the `removeAttr` line.